# if function not being triggered although result variable has the correct value in it

Tags: php, jquery, post, if-statement, subscription

So I am writing this subscribe page..when the user clicks submit it should send the email to the database..I am using jQuery's post method so upon submission a result of sent should be returned and if this is true the button should disappear and a sent message should appear however this is not happening when I use the console.log to print the result value it says success but the if statement is going to the else clause and printing the error message.

```
$.post("send_email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
    console.log(result);
    //and after the ajax request ends we check       the text returned
    if(result == "sent"){

        //if the mail is sent remove the submit paragraph
        $('#button').remove();
        //and show the mail success div with fadeIn
        $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
    }else{
        console.log('going to failure clause');
        //show the mail failed div
        $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
        //reenable the submit button by removing attribute disabled and change the text back to Send The Message
        $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `result` doesn't contain any white-space? If it does then the place to fix it would be in your PHP, but hypothetically if you don't control the PHP you could change your `if` condition to allow for white-space, perhaps: `if (result.replace(/\s/g,"") === "sent") {...`

Comment: yeah it doesnt
    function success()
   {
  die ("sent");
   }//end success function

Comment: I used if (result.replace(/\s/g,"") === "sent") {... to allow  whitespaces and it fixed it thanks nnnnn. Thanks to everyone else for contributing

Comment: OK, cool, I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your PHP response includes white-space that isn't obvious when you log `result`. If that can't be fixed in the PHP code for some reason then you can update your JS if condition to ignore white-space as follows:

```
if (result.replace(/\s/g,"") === "sent") {
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I use the console.log to print the result value it says success

So, doesn't this:

```
                    if(result == "sent"){
```

need to be this:

```
                    if(result == "success"){
```

?